# Convergence of the sequence, $\frac 1n$

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Why does the sequence $\frac 1n$, where $n$ is a natural number , does not converge when R is endowed with the discrete metric ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequence $1/n$ converges to $0$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for every $k > n$ $$d(\frac1k,0) < \varepsilon.$$ Since $d$ is the discrete metric and $\frac1k > 0$, $d(\frac1k,0) = 1$. So if you take for example $\varepsilon=\frac12$ there is no $n$ as required above.

Comment: This doesn't directly point out an answer to the question, why does the sequence not converge?  This answer points out why the sequence does not converge to $0$.

Comment: That's true. However the argument above can be easily modified to prove that only constant sequences (after some point) converge.

Answer (score 5):

The sequence fails to be Cauchy because the distance between any two terms in the sequence is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the discrete metric the only converging sequences are the constant sequences from some point on.

In the case of $\{1/n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric $d$ we have
$$
d(1/n,0)=1.
$$

Comment: The first sentence covers it, but the second part points out explicitly only why the sequence does not converge to $0$, not why it does not converge.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I took the liberty to interpret the question as Why the sequence does not converge to $0$?. In view of the accepted answer, I think it was a correct interpretartion.